# Apache Spark and Spring Transaction Management

Tags: java, spring, transactions, apache-spark, jdbctemplate

I am using Apache Spark in Clustered environment with 3 workers.
From Spark's 'foreachpartition', I am sending data in batches to Spring jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate in a transaction Mode.

I dont have much idea about spring transactions. For Spring transaction I am using below code :

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition paramTransactionDefinition = new     
DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus status = 
transactionManager.getTransaction(paramTransactionDefinition );

//sql and jdbcArgs preparation...
//....
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(finalSql, jdbcArgs);
            transactionManager.commit(status);
```

above code is getting called like :

```
.foreachpartition(...params..) {
   call(..params..) {
      if(basicDataSource == null || transactionManager == null) {
         BasicDataSource bds = getBasicDataSource(basicDatasrc,  
                                             isTransactionRequired);//for transaction

         transactionManager2.setDataSource(bds);//DataSourceTransactionManager

         jdbcTemplate.setBasicDataSource(bds);
         // initializing dataSource to transactionManager and jdbcTemplate both because read somewhere that connection object instance should be same for transactionManager and jdbcTemplate.
      }//end of if          
     // here call to above transaction and jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate code goes
   }//end of call
   private BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDs = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDs.setUsername(sparkDs.getUsername());
        basicDs.setPassword(sparkDs.getPassword());
        basicDs.setUrl(sparkDs.getUrl());
        basicDs.setDriverClassName(sparkDs.getDriverClassName());
        basicDs.setMaxActive(sparkDs.getMaxActive());
        basicDs.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
   }//end of getDatasource


}
```

I am not closing connections here, as I saw in jdbcTemplate code that the connections are released by spring itself.
Now, the issue is : above code of transaction doesn't write complete data to DB.
When I don't use transaction, then there isn't any problem.

My question is, Is above the right way of creating datasource and transaction ? 
Because above code gets executed on 3 workers with 40 partitions. Though the basicDatasource doesn't gets created 40 times but it is getting created 5-8 times.

Can somebody please help me here.

Comment: Can you check the TransactionStatus after commit to see if there are any exceptions?

Comment: @urug : Yes I checked the status as : `status.isCompleted` and it returns true. Even the number of records return by `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` are same as expected.